# Two rows corresponding to adjacent vertices of a tree cannot both be linear combinations of the other rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree and $A$ its corresponding adjacency matrix. Let $u,v \in V(T)$ and $u$ is adjacent to $v$.

> If the row corresponding to $u$ is a linear combination of the other rows of $A$, then prove that the row corresponding to $v$ cannot be written
>   as a linear combination of the other rows of $A$.

I can prove it when $u$ is pendant but couldn't prove it in general. Any help is appreciated.

**Example**

Take $T$ as path on $7$ vertices, $u=3$ and $v=2$ or $5$.
Here $R_3=R_1+R_5-R_7$ but we can see that $R_2$ can't be written in any linear combination of rows in $A$. Same is the case with $R_4$.

Comment: @ M. Vinay, I edited the question. I hope it's clear now. Can you please look at?

Comment: An equivalent way to state this is: Let $T$ be a tree with vertices $1, 2, \ldots, n$, and let $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$ respectively be the corresponding rows of the adjacency matrix of $T$. Prove that if vertices $1$ and $2$ are adjacent in $T$, and $r_1 \in \operatorname{Span}\{r_3, \ldots, r_n\}$, then $r_2 \not\in \operatorname{Span}\{r_3, \ldots, r_n\}$.

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The statement holds vacuously for a tree of one vertex.  So we assume the tree $T$ has two or more vertices.  A tree of two or more vertices is a bipartite graph.  We alternately color the vertices of $T$ blue and red.  Let us order the vertex labels so that all of the blue vertices of $T$ come first, followed by all of the red vertices of $T$.  Then the adjacency matrix of $T$ takes the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B\\ B' & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the rows of $B$ are indexed by blue vertices and the columns by red vertices.

If a row of $A$ is a linear combination of other rows of $A$, or equivalently, if there is a linear combination of rows of $A$ that equals $0$, then there is a linear combination of rows of $B$ that equals $0$ or there is a linear combination of rows of $B'$ that equals $0$.  The latter is equivalent to there being a linear combination of columns of $B$ that equals $0$.

The matrix elements $1$ in $B$ are identified with the edges of $T$.  The proposition to be proved can now be restated as follows:

> Let there be a linear combination of rows of $B$ that equals $0$, and let $E$ be the set of edges incident on the vertices corresponding to those rows.  Let there be a linear combination of columns of $B$ that equals $0$, and let $E'$ be the set of edges incident on the vertices corresponding to those columns.  Then $E$ and $E'$ are disjoint.

Here's a proof.  Linear combinations of columns of $B$ that equal $0$ correspond to elements of the kernel of $B$ (or null space of $B$, or right null space of $B$), that is, they correspond to vectors $v$ such that $Bv=0$.  Linear combinations of rows of $B$ that equal $0$ correspond to elements of the cokernel of $B$ (or left null space of $B$), that is, they correspond to vectors $u$ such that $uB=0$.

We can always find a set of rational vectors that form a basis for the kernel (or cokernel) of $B$ and, by rescaling, we can make these integer vectors.  More can be said, however.  We can, in fact, choose bases for the kernel and cokernel of $B$ that consist entirely of vectors with elements in $\{-1,0,1\}$.  These basis vectors can be identified with certain special subtrees of $T$.

To see this, suppose that we have a linear combination of columns of $B$ (with nonzero coefficients) that equals $0$.  Let $C_a$ be one of the columns that appears in this linear combination.  Let $S_a$ be the set of positions in which $C_a$ contains an element $1$.  Since $S_a$ is certainly nonempty, there is a $k\in S_a$.  Then there has to be another column appearing in the linear combination, say $C_b$, that also has a $1$ in position $k$.  Now $C_a$ and $C_b$ can have no other $1$s in common position, for otherwise there would be a cycle, contradicting that $T$ is a tree.  (This follows because $a$ and $b$ are red vertices, which would both be connected to the same two blue vertices, forming a quadrilateral.)  Let $S_{a,b}$ be the set of positions, apart from $k$, in which either $C_a$ or $C_b$ contains a $1$.  If $S_{a,b}$ is nonempty, then pick one of these positions, say $l$.  Then there is a third column, $C_c$, appearing in the linear combination, that contains a $1$ in position $l$.  Furthermore, $C_c$ contains no other $1$s in common positions with $C_a$ or $C_b$, for otherwise a cycle would be formed.

We may continue in this way, for example letting $S_{a,b,c}$ be the set of positions apart from $k$ and $l$ in which one of $C_a$, $C_b$, $C_c$ contains a $1$, then, if $S_{a,b,c}$ is nonempty, selecting one of its elements $m$ and identifying another column $C_d$ in the linear combination that has a $1$ in position $m$.  The process continues until $S_{a,b,c,d,\ldots}$ is empty.  Clearly the last column to be added corresponds to a leaf, since otherwise there would be a new element $1$ needing to be matched.

The result of this process is a set of columns $\mathcal{C}=\{C_a,C_b,\ldots\}$, which corresponds to a set of red vertices $\{a,b,\ldots\}$.  Each of the red vertices in this set has a neighboring blue vertex in common with exactly one other red vertex in the set.  These red and blue vertices, together with the edges that join them form a subtree of $T$.  Every blue vertex in this subtree has degree $2$; every red vertex in this subtree has degree equal to its degree in $T$.  We will call a subtree of $T$ with these two properties a **kernel basis tree**.  The leaves of a kernel basis tree are all red.

There is a linear combination of the columns in $\mathcal{C}$ with all coefficients equal to $-1$ or $1$ that equals the zero vector.  This linear combination is formed by giving $C_a$ the coefficient $1$, giving $C_b$ the coefficient $-1$, and, in general, giving each column the coefficient of sign opposite that of the column of $\mathcal{C}$ that contains a $1$ in common position with it.  In this way, we obtain a vector with elements in $\{-1,0,1\}$ ($0$ for the columns not in $\mathcal{C}$) that is in the kernel of $B$.  Equivalently, this vector may be obtained by picking any red vertex, say vertex $a$, of the kernel basis tree.  This vertex, and all red vertices of the kernel basis tree whose distance from $a$ is a multiple of $4$ will have coefficient $1$.  All red vertices in the kernel basis tree whose distance from $a$ is an odd multiple of $2$ will have coefficient $-1$.  All red vertices not in the kernel basis tree will have coefficient $0$.

Let the linear combination we started with be associated with the vector $v$ in the kernel of $B$.  Let the coefficient of $C_a$ in that linear combination, that is, the $a^\text{th}$ element of $v$, be denoted $v_a$.  Let $w$ be the vector in the kernel associated with the kernel basis tree.  This is the vector that was constructed in the previous paragraph, and has $w_a=1$.  Now form the vector $y=v-v_aw$, which is also in the kernel of $B$.  By construction $y_a=0$, and any nonzero elements of $y$ occur in positions in which $v$ also had nonzero element.  If $y$ is not the zero vector, we may repeat the entire process above on the linear combination of columns of $B$ that corresponds to $y$.  This will produce a second kernel basis tree and hence a second kernel vector with elements in $\{-1,0,1\}$, a suitable multiple of which may be subtracted from $y$.  The process may be repeated finitely many times until the zero vector is obtained.  By this means, any vector in the kernel of $B$ may be expressed as a linear combination of $\{-1,0,1\}$ vectors corresponding to to kernel basis trees.

We may apply a similar process to the cokernel, focusing on rows rather than columns.  By the same reasoning, any cokernel vector is a linear combination of $\{-1,0,1\}$ vectors associated with **cokernel basis trees**, defined to be subtrees of $T$ with the properties that

1. every blue vertex of the subtree has degree equal to its degree in $T$;
2. every red vertex of the subtree has degree $2$.

The leaves of a cokernel basis tree are all blue.

The proposition now boils down to the statement that no kernel basis tree shares an edge with a cokernel basis tree.  This may be proved by contradiction.  Suppose kernel basis tree $T_R$ and cokernel basis tree $T_B$ have an edge $e$ in common.  (The subscripts $R$ and $B$ are to remind us that the leaves of $T_R$ are red and those of $T_B$ are blue.)  If the blue endpoint of $e$ is a leaf, we have an immediate contradiction because every blue vertex in $T_R$ must be incident on exactly two edges of $T_R$.  If it is not a leaf, then there is an incident edge other than $e$ that is contained in both $T_R$ and $T_B$.  Similar reasoning applies to the red endpoint of $e$, producing either a contradiction with the property that every red vertex in $T_B$ is incident on exactly two edges of $T_B$, or a new edge that is in both $T_R$ and $T_B$.  If we have not yet arrived at a contradiction, we may repeat the reasoning for either of these new edges.  Since $T$ is a finite tree, we will eventually reach a leaf, and hence a contradiction.

**Example 1:** For the tree below, the matrix $B$, with rows indexed by $1$, $2$, $3$ and columns indexed by $4$, $5$, $6$ is
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The cokernel of $B$ has dimension $1$ and is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to the cokernel basis tree highlighted in blue.

[image: cokernel basis tree for six vertex graph]

The kernel of $B$ also has dimension $1$ and is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.  This corresponds to the kernel basis tree highlighted in red.

[image: kernel basis tree for six vertex graph]

Observe that the blue and red subtrees have no edge in common.

**Example 2:** The path $P_5$ below has
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The kernel of $B$ is zero dimensional; the cokernel is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to the cokernel basis tree highlighted in blue.  (It equals $P_5$.)

[image]

It is vacuously true that no kernel basis tree shares an edge with a cokernel basis tree.

**Example 3:** The path $P_4$ below has
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The kernel and cokernel of $B$ are both zero dimensional.

[image]

**Example 4:** For the tree below, the matrix $B$, with rows indexed by $1$, $2$, ..., $11$ and columns indexed by $12$, $13$, ..., $21$ is
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The cokernel of $B$ has dimension $2$ and is spanned by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which correspond to the cokernel basis trees highlighted in blue.

[image]

[image]

The kernel of $B$ has dimension $1$ and is spanned by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
which corresponds to the kernel basis tree below, highlighted in red.

[image]

Observe that neither of the blue subtrees shares an edge with the red subtree.

Comment: @Sry: thank you for awarding the bounty.  If there are any aspects of my answer that need elaboration or further justification, let me know.

Comment: @ Will Orrick: Can you please explain how "Proving $E$ and $E'$ are disjoint, proves the question asked."

Comment: @rational: Let there be a linear combination of rows of $B$ that equals $0$ and a linear combination of columns of $B$ that equals $0$.  If $E$ and $E'$ are not disjoint, then there is at least one $1$ of $B$ that is in both a row of the row linear combination, say the row corresponding to vertex $u$, and in a column of the column linear combination, say the column corresponding to vertex $v$.  So there is a $1$ in row $u$ and column $v$.  That means that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent vertices.

Comment: @rational: Conversely, suppose that vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent blue and red vertices, and that there is both a linear combination of rows of $B$, including row $u$, that equals $0$ and a linear combination of columns of $B$, including column $v$, that equals $0$.  Then both $E$ and $E'$ contain the edge between $u$ and $v$.